# How to add a friend in an Android App?

Tags: java, android, facebook

In my phone contact book, When I click on any of the contact, it displays the contact name and the phone number in the logcat, which are passed to the server as parameters of a POST call. What I want is, the moment I click on any contact, it should be added in my friend list as well.

Now, clicking on contact, gives me the name and number, how do I display this name in the form of a picture, so that the user can see that a friend has been added in his friend list.

Just to make my question more clear, when someone doesn't have a profile picture on facebook, and when you add this person as a friend, his name is displayed along with the image of human form. I want to achieve this in my App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a dummy image stored in your drawables that if the user doesn't have a photo, you just use the dummy image.

Comment: Thanks, but, how do I associate this picture with a particular name? When more friends are added, how do I display the second picture beside first picture? How do I display this name in the form of a picture, so that the user can see that a friend has been added in his friend list? Can you give some examples with codes. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about pictures or layout?

Comment: When I'll click on the Add Friend button, it would open my contact list, I'll select/click any name from my contact list, now the selected name should appear below the human image. How do I display this human image? How do I display name below the human image? How do I make sure that when more friends are added, the "Add Friend" should shift towards right and let more human images with the name, be added? All this happens in an Activity.